# Common properties for all profile of one service: spring cloud config

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, properties-file, spring-cloud-config

I would like to setup common properties across all profile for one single service. How it can be done? For now I have following structure

```
application.properies
service1
   profile1
       service1.properties
   profile2
       service1.properties
service2
   profile1
       service2.properties
   profile2
       service2.properties
```

How can I share common properties for all profiles of `service1`?

Comment: Add files with profile in name such as service1-profile1.properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define these properties in `bootstrap.yml` or `bootstrap.properties` file:

```
application:
    name: "service1"

cloud:
    config:
      uri: "http://<hostname>:<port>"

# ... more common properties
```